# Immutable vs mutable object as returned parameter for class method

Tags: object-oriented, encapsulation, static-methods, immutability, mutable

There is a class method (static method) in which I create and build some object. And for filling that object, I create it as mutable object.

My mutable object is a subclass of immutable object. So i can return it as super Class type.

That object is just created in class method and returns. It is not a part of object or class state.

**Should I return mutable object or it immutable copy?** (what solution will be correct in concept of **encapsulation**)

For example there is some pseudo code:

```
// MutableArray is subclass of Array
MutableArray : Array;

// Another class

static (Array *)getEngineers {
   Array *employees = Array.arrayWithContentsOfResource("employees.txt");
   MutableArray *engineers = new MutableArray;
   for (Employee *employee in employees) {
      if (employee.profession == "Engineer") {
         engineers.addObject(employee)
      }    
   }
   return engineers; // should I return Array.arrayWithArray(engineers) instead of engineers ?
}
```

**Update:**

I mean, if I have a mutable array that is a member of the object, then it makes sense to return immutable copy in getter method (to provide access control and encapsulation). But if I have method like in example. I need only immutable object for using. But creating immutable copy of array is additional operations. Does it make sense to make it immutable?

Comment: Hey Pavel, maybe you could join [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) to talk about how your question could be improved? It's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking about here, and what your reasoning is for either choice

Comment: What is immutable in `Array` that becomes mutable with `MutableArray`? The container itself (you can't add/delete elements from `Array`), the elements held by the container or both?

Comment: f.e. NSArray and NSMutableArray (objective-c foundation), for NSMutableArray you can add and remove objects after initializing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if only your team is using this code in the same process then i would return the same object (mutable object) . keep it simple and fast. Your own team would not change something on the objects unless they needed to, and if they did then they would have to make another copy.

If I was making a API too I would not keep it immutable, simple because engineer looks like its an object that can change (like if the object had something like reporting To or degrees-held - that can change over time.

Objects should mimic their real world counter parts as much as possible. Some attributes could be immutable (like date of birth etc)

Good external docs or code comments could explain how to use the object where required

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation doesn't have anything to do with immutability.  Well, maybe it does a little.  A more accurate term would be "access control."  An immutable object restricts access control because you cannot write it; you can only read it.

You make objects immutable when you are using them in a multi-threaded context, and you want to make your code more... "deterministic."  There is no right or wrong about this, no "correct" or "incorrect;" if you're not using multiple threads, you probably don't need to worry about immutability at all.

Make objects immutable when you want to guarantee "safe" access to the object via another thread.  An object is "safe" to access in a multi-threaded context when you can guarantee that another thread won't be writing an object while you're trying to read it.  You can do this with immutability, but you can also do it with locks, mutexes, semaphores and other concurrency mechanisms.

Comment: To be fair multi-threading isn't the only scenario where you make objects immutable. Immutable objects allow you to verify their state during construction and then never have to do so again since they can't have their state changed to invalid later. For this reason I make objects that deal with unmanaged resources immutable usually. Also since the validity is only tested at one point, that means only one place in consuming code do you need to worry about your object complaining about invalidity. After construction, every other part of code consuming the object can know it's valid.

Comment: I guess my point is there's no such thing as "correct."  Asking simply for "which way is correct" in this scenario is meaningless, because the answer is "it depends."  However, feel free to enumerate all of the use cases for immutables and let the OP pick the one that fits. :)

Comment: True, I deliberately didn't answer this question because it's pretty vague

Comment: I mean, if I have a mutable array that is a member of the object, then it makes sense to return immutable copy in getter method (to provide access control and encapsulation). But if I have method like in example. I need only immutable object for using. But creating immutable copy of array is additional operations. Does it make sense to make it immutable?

Comment: It does if you need the features and benefits that making an object immutable provides.

Comment: Immutable objects are not only about multi-threading, like Jimmy Hoffa correctly pointed out. Making an object immutable also makes it simpler to reason about single-threaded code: for example, if I see `x` mentioned somewhere, more code follows, then `x` again, I know it represents exactly the same value or object state as before; I don't even have to look at the function calls in between.

Comment: Read-only objects restrict access and don't allow writing, but immutability goes beyond access control.  For a reference to identify an immutable object, it is not only necessary that the reference not be usable to modify any encapsulated state, but also that no reference to any part of the encapsulated state exists anywhere that can ever be exposed to code which would be capable of mutating that state.

Comment: @supercat: I would imagine that you need a language specifically designed for immutability to achieve what you describe.  In C#, you can modify private members of an object via Reflection, but that's generally understood to be "breaking the rules."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Contractual immutability may be achieved by wrapping in a read-only object the only extant references to newly-created copies of mutable objects.  Contractual immutability is not achieved, however, by a read-only object which wraps a passed-in reference unless the supplier of the reference contractually promises that the instance thereby will never be exposed to anything that could legitimately modify it.

Comment: @supercat: You must be referring to e.g. the ability to modify mutable elements of an immutable array in some languages, notably Java and C#.  My point is that if you write your code in a way that achieves immutability (i.e. by not writing to mutable objects), then you obtain the benefits of immutability, even if you don't get the enforcement of immutability.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: One can achieve the benefits of immutability without compiler/framework enforcement, if any code which expects something to be immutable can guarantee that no reference to the object will ever be exposed to code which wouldn't be contractually forbidden to modify it.  Most read-only wrappers do not impose such a contractual requirement upon code that passes in the objects to be wrapped, and should not promise immutability unless they either impose such a requirement or make private copies of any potentially-mutable data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the use of this mutable/immutable Array, perhaps one factor to consider is the lifetime of the Array. Are you going to store the Array object for later use or pass it around to other parts of your code? If so, then an immutable object might be better because it reduces the chance of accidentally (or perhaps maliciously) having the Engineer array changed. If this is a one-time use, then you might be able to get away with a mutable array because the exposure of that array is already minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass shouldn't violate the contract that the super-class has with its clients.

It isn't *automatically* true that returning something mutable when the client expects something immutable will violate that contract, but I'm assuming the super-class returns something immutable for a reason, and that clients therefore expect to have an immutable object returned.  So, unless you have specific knowledge that it's OK in this case, don't break any client code relying on immutability - return something immutable.

(An example of what might go wrong - maybe classes written to work with the super-class never check its state because they assume it was checked on creation and can't be modified.  Then it gets an instance of your class, and fails to verify it is currently in a valid state).